# Message queue 'number of messages' is always 0

Tags: c#, windows-7, msmq, message-queue

I am trying to send messages to MSMQ on Windows 7 using C#. The code is as below:

```
using(var q = new MessageQueue(".\Private$\hellomsmq"))
{
    q.Send(new Message());
}
```

But when I refresh in Computer Management the 'number of messages' (Message Queuing/Private Queues/hellomsmq) stays at 0. I did not get any exceptions/errors while performing send().

Can anyone help please. Thanks!

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question. Are the messages being consumed?

Comment: all i am doing is call send in a console app. that s all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that queue transactional? If so. I believe you have to send your message as a transaction or use the two-parameter version of `Send` with `MessageQueueTransactionType.Single` as the second parameter.